# SQL Remove Duplicates, save lowest of certain column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I've been looking for an answer to this but couldn't find anything the same as this particular situation.

So I have a one table that I want to remove duplicates from.

```
    __________________
   | JobNumber-String |
   | JobOp -   Number |
    ------------------
```

So there are multiples of these two values, together they make the key for the row. I want keep all distinct job numbers with the lowest job op. How can I do this? I've tried a bunch of things, mainly trying the min function, but that only seems to work on the entire table not just the JobNumber sets. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original Table Values:

```
JobNumber   Jobop
123          100
123          101
456          200
456          201
780          300
```

Code Ran:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE CONCAT(JobNumber,JobOp) NOT IN 
    (
    SELECT CONCAT(JobNumber,MIN(JobOp))
    FROM table
    GROUP BY JobNumber
    )
```

Ending Table Values:

```
JobNumber   Jobop
123          100
456          200
780          300
```

Comment: Perfect that worked, Thanks I didn't know about basically making a new key. In SQL Server 2008 at least its just a plus between the values

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2008 or higher you can enhance the MIN function with an OVER clause specifying a PARTITION BY section.

Please have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select the values you want to keep:

```
select jobOp, min(number) from table group by jobOp
```

Then you can delete the records you don't want:

```
DELETE t FROM table t 
left JOIN (select jobOp, min(number) as minnumber from table group by jobOp )  e
 ON t.jobob = e.jobob and t.number = e.minnumber
Where e.jobob is null
```

Comment: number is the type. like 20 or 10. Plus your answer has nothing to do with the job number

Answer (score 0):

I like to do this with window functions:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, min(jobop) over (partition by numbers) as minjop
      from table t
     )
delete from todelete
    where jobop > minjop;
```

Comment: Actually since there could be two records with the same min value this might not remove that duplicate. It would be better to use the ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by numbers ORDER BY jobs) AS RowNum and delete all rows that don't have a 1 with todelete as (
      select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by numbers order by jobop) as rownum
      from table t
     )
delete from todelete
    where rownum > 1;

Comment: @JosephGagliardo . . . Read the question:  "So there are multiples of these two values, together they make the key for the row."  That would imply that there are no duplicates.

Comment: Fair enough, that wasn't immediately obvious. So in this case the min works just fine. Nevertheless it is a good added bit of advice to consider using Row_Number if that were not the case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not using the correct GROUP BY clause when using the `MIN` function. This sql should give you the minimum JobOp value for each JobNumber:

```
SELECT JobNumber, MIN(JobOp) FROM test.so_test GROUP BY JobNumber;
```

Using this in a subquery, along with `CONCAT` (this is from MySQL, SQL Server might use different function) because both fields form your key, gives you this sql:

```
SELECT * FROM so_test WHERE CONCAT(JobNumber,JobOp) 
NOT IN (SELECT CONCAT(JobNumber,MIN(JobOp)) FROM test.so_test GROUP BY JobNumber);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, the other answer was a little more thorough, but thank you!